# Installing Packages and getting Eslint Version Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.31.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"*" from eslint-import-resolver-typescript@2.7.1
npm ERR!   8 more (eslint-plugin-es, eslint-plugin-import, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm ERR!   eslint-config-next@"^12.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.23.0" from eslint-config-next@12.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-next
npm ERR!     eslint-config-next@"^12.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

When I'm trying to install a package

Comment: do `npm install` in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my package.json was messed up. At "dependencies"{

"eslint": 12.0.4"

and it shouldve said "8.28.0"